# OrmLite query for date in joined table

Tags: android, ormlite

I'm trying to build a query like this with ormLite:

```
SELECT `classA`.* 
FROM `classA` 
LEFT JOIN `classB` ON `classA`.`idField` = `classB`.`fkField` 
WHERE `classB`.`dateField` >= '2015-11-16';
```

The dateField on classB looks like this:

```
@DatabaseField
private Date dateField;
```

So the date is persisted in ormLite's default format (e.g '2012-07-13 00:00:00.000000')

This is my approach in ormLite:

```
QueryBuilder<ClassA, Long> qbA = mDbHelper.getClassADao().queryBuilder();
QueryBuilder<ClassB, Integer> qbB = mDbHelper.getClassBDao().queryBuilder();
qbClassB.where().ge("dateField", new DateTime().minusDays(100).toDate());
qbA.leftJoin(qbB);
List<ClassA> list = qbA.query();
```

LogCat:

```
D/BaseMappedStatement: prepared statement 'SELECT `classA`.* FROM `classA` LEFT JOIN `classB` ON `classA`.`idField` = `classB`.`fkField` WHERE `classB`.`dateField` >= ? ' with 1 args
D/StatementExecutor: query of 'SELECT `classA`.* FROM `classA` LEFT JOIN `classB` ON `classA`.`idField` = `classB`.`fkField` WHERE `classB`.`dateField` >= ? ' returned 0 results
```

The raw query works fine and returns the desired results.
The ormLite query returns an empty resultList.
Does anyone have any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: "dateTield" did you misspelled that field? Also you could try to do the same date format as in database

Comment: @Orest Typo during posting. Question edited.

Comment: if you will comment out this row qbClassB.where().ge("dateField", new DateTime().minusDays(100).toDate()); query will work and return all rows from join?

Comment: yep, it does. join is not the problem

Comment: And there are rows in the table with date greater then "new DateTime().minusDays(100).toDate()" ?

Comment: sqlite> select count(*) from classB where dateField >= '2015-11-16 11:03:28.000832';
16

sqlite> select count(*) from classB where dateField >= '2015-11-16';
16